# how to run a external daemon-process then kill it in anytime

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to achieve this.

I can run the process by os.system('PROCESS_NAME &')

But I don't know how to kill it.

And I don't wanna the external process blocking in my process

```
run external daemon process

do my jobs, do anything

kill the `running external daemon process`
```

On Linux OS, I wonder kill the task when meets some requirement

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: When do you want to kill the process? After a certain period of time, or only after you have completed all your jobs?